# Error: projects/custom-lib/src/lib/components/accordion/accordion.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ngb-accordion' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-library

So, I have created an **Angular Library Project** that I am consuming in my application source without publishing (as of now).

The reason to create this library is to setup some common components which will be created by skinning (changing scss) **ng-bootstrap** library and then consumed in various pages of the application.

So far, I have successfully skinned a few components already where no custom tags were used i.e. Tabs, Datepickers etc. and it all worked as expected and I could export these as part of my Library Level Module which I later imported where needed in my app.

Now, I am planning to also skin the ng-accordion but it is different from the other provided components i.e. it has custom tags `<ngb-accordion>` , `<ngb-panel>` etc. using which gives me the following error (while building),

```
Error: projects/custom-lib/src/lib/components/accordion/custom-lib-accordion.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ngb-accordion' is not a known element: 
1. If 'ngb-accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 
2. If 'ngb-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

What I have tried ?

I assumed the reason for this error as the custom-tag being used which during the library build angular can't understand and ending up throwing this. So, I have added the `@angular/elements` package to my project and specified this tag in the `customElements`, so as to make angular aware of this custom tag which is coming from `ng-bootstrap`. **But the build still fails with the same error.**

Following is my code snippet,

**component.html**

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" class="custom-accordion" (panelChange)="changeArrow($event,acc)"> 
  <ngb-panel *ngFor="let faq of faqs" id="faq-{{faq.id}}"> 
    <ng-template ngbPanelHeader> 
      <h5 class="custom-accordion__title_text">{{ faq.question }}</h5> 
      <div class="custom-accordion__title_button"> 
        <button class="btn btn-link p-0" ngbPanelToggle> 
          <ng-container *ngIf="selectedPanelId.includes(faq.id)"> 
            <ng-container *ngIf="closeOpenedPanel"> 
              <i class="custom-icon custom-down-icon"></i> 
            </ng-container> 
            <ng-container *ngIf="!closeOpenedPanel"> 
              <i class="custom-icon custom-up-icon"></i> 
            </ng-container> 
          </ng-container> 
          <ng-container *ngIf="!selectedPanelId.includes(faq.id)"> 
            <i class="custom-icon custom-down-icon"></i> 
          </ng-container> 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    </ng-template> 
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent> {{faq.answer}} </ng-template> 
  </ngb-panel> 
</ngb-accordion>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NgbPanelChangeEvent } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
 
export interface FAQ { 
  id: string; 
  question: string; 
  answer: string; 
} 
 
@Component({ 
  selector: 'custom-accordion', 
  templateUrl: './custom-accordion.component.html', 
  styles: [` 
      @import "variables/variables"; 
 
      @include custom-media(">sm") { 
      ::ng-deep .card { 
        .card-header { 
          justify-content: space-between; 
          padding: 1.5rem 0; 
          margin-bottom: 0; 
        } 
        .card-body { 
          padding: 0; 
        } 
        .collapse { 
          &.show { 
            font-size: 1rem; 
            padding: 0 0 1.5rem 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            max-width: 70%; 
          } 
        } 
      } 
 
      &__title_text { 
        font-size: 0.875rem; 
        max-width: 70%; 
        padding-right: 0; 
      } 
     } 
  `], 
}) 
export class CustomAccordionComponent { 
  @Input() public faqs: FAQ[]; 
  closeOpenedPanel: boolean = false; 
  selectedPanelId: string = 'ngb-panel-'; 
 
  constructor() { } 
 
  /** 
   * To change the accordion arrow direction 
   * we check the current active-panel (clicked/interacted) 
   * first and then also check whether the panel is currently open. 
   */ 
  changeArrow($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent, acc: any) { 
    this.selectedPanelId = $event.panelId; 
    if (acc.isExpanded(this.selectedPanelId)) { 
      this.closeOpenedPanel = true; 
    } else { 
      this.closeOpenedPanel = false; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

**module.ts** - This will export the custom component created above.

```
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements'; 
import { NgbAccordionModule, NgbAccordion, NgbAccordionConfig, NgbPanel } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
import { CustomAccordionComponent } from './custom-accordion.component'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
 
 
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, NgbAccordionModule], 
    declarations: [CustomAccordionComponent], 
    entryComponents: [CustomAccordionComponent], 
}) 
export class CustomAccordionModule { 
    constructor(private injector: Injector) { } 
 
    public ngDoBootstrap(): void { 
 
        const c1: any = createCustomElement(CustomAccordionComponent , { injector: this.injector }); 
 
        if (!customElements.get('ngb-accordion')) { 
            customElements.define('ngb-accordion', c1); 
        } 
 
    } 
}
```

**home.page.html** - usage.

```
<custom-accordion [faqs]="faqs"></custom-accordion>
```

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [ 
    CommonModule, 
    CustomModule, 
    ComponentsModule, 
    PageRoutingModule, 
    NgbModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    FormsModule, 
  ], 
  declarations: [...], 
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] 
}) 
export class HomeModule { }
```

Not sure, what is that I am missing. The same code works just fine when used right away in the application. Therefore, I am sure it is this custom `ngb-accordion` tag that is causing this. Please suggest me a direction to get around this, if you can point it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you're creating a custom element (web component), angular is just not aware that this is a component you want to use.

In the module where you use the component you'll need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` as following:

```
@NgModule({
// imports, exports, etc
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

Probably you're also lacking to add this component in the `exports`-array in your declaring module

Comment: Did it , still the same. I don't know how but I got this working in the past. Not really sure what I did there but I am sure I am missing something here.